# Does projections to orthogonal summands closed $\implies$ subspace closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $X$ be a inner product space, with orthogonal decomposition $X=V \oplus W$. Give $X$ the topology induced by the norm induced by the inner product. Let $E\subset X$ be a subspace such that the projections to $V, W$ (call them $\pi_V(E), \pi_W(E)$) are closed. Does this imply that $E$ is closed itself?

Note that $X$ may not be complete; in fact I am mainly interested in the case where it is not complete. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: Even if it is not complete, is the topology in X given by the norm induced by the inner product?

Comment: @Pozz Yes, the topology on $X$ is that induced by the norm. Sorry for not saying that.